# Does Gnaw turrets die when Gnaw does?

Tags: awesomenauts

When I die (playing Gnaw), a friend of mine noticed all my turrets vanish. Is this verified ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they vanish when the user dies.

It's more obvious when you die after having tossed down plants in places where enemies rarely go (e.g. right next to a turret they aren't attacking). You can easily and painlessly test this yourself by going into a practice game, grabbing seedlings first.

If an area is filled with seedlings and you're unable to get rid of them yourself, consider destroying the Gnaw who spawned them. It's harder or easier depending on how defensively the Gnaw is playing and how well equipped you are to deal with Gnaw's physical harrassment.